# Size of figure too big - How to compress without qualityloss in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a figure with subplots, whereas each subplot features as contourplot.
As it turns out, if I save it to .pdf, the size of the figure is 50mb. Is there
a way to compress the figure without having such a big quality loss as seen in .png?

thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you can reduce the grid step, which will in turn reduce the number of line segments proportionally. If this doesn't suit you, you will have to switch to a smoother representation than polylines, such as splines, which will allow you a coarser grid with high curve quality. I have no idea if matplotlib allows that.

Comment: Could you please post the code you are using to produce your figure and also an image of the resulting figure you are producing please.

Comment: why not use the `dpi` option in savefig?